# Como podría enviar un campo de una tabla como subcadena en otro campo de otra tabla. - INSTR(CAMPOSCH, CAMPO_BUSCADO,1,1)

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

mi problema consiste en lo siguiente: tengo 2 tablas( `pcr` y `sivigila`).  Debo consultar si el campo `documento_pcr`, se encuentra en el campo `documento_sivigila`. El problema se me presenta cuando al cruzar el `campo_pcr` no es encontrado en `sivigila`, porque a veces este documento es una *subcadena* del campo `documento_sivigila`.

Ejemplo, tengo en `pcr` la cadena **85472449** pero en `sivigila` este documento posiblemente se encuentra como **XDVEN85472449AS**, lo que le indica al motor que la cadena buscada no se encuentra y esto hace que el informe generado sea herrado.

He tratado generando la siguiente consulta, para poder ver que cadenas son > 0 y poder identificar cuales se encuentran en `sivigila`.

```
select pcr_documento as "DOCUMENTO"
     , instr(siv_documento, pcr_documento, 1, 1) as "Posicion de CADENA" 
from pcr, sivigila;
```

Se ejecuta la consulta, pero parece que me bloquea el motor de BD, ya que demora horas y no muestra nada.

Cabe aclarar que la tabla de `pcr` cuenta con mas de **un millón de registros**, y `sivigila` cuenta con **600 mil registros** aproximados.

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de abordar este problema?

Comment: Hola, puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el **operador in**:

```
select pcr_documento as "DOCUMENTO"      
from pcr p
where pcr_documento in (select siv_documento 
                        from sivigila s
                        where instr(s.siv_documento, p.pcr_documento, 1, 1)
```

Aquí hacemos una **subconsulta** que devuelve un conjunto de resultados de los documentos pcr que están dentro de la **tabla sivigila** y sobre esta **subconsulta** aplicas el **operador in** desde la **consulta primaria**. La **consulta primaria** devuelve todos los documentos pcr que se encuentran en los registros devueltos por la **subconsulta**.

También puedes probar con esta consulta:

```
select pcr_documento as "DOCUMENTO"      
from pcr p, sivigila s
where instr(s.siv_documento, p.pcr_documento, 1, 1)
```

De esta forma haces un **producto cartesiano** entre ambas tablas y filtras teniendo en cuenta los documentos pcr que se encuentran en la **tabla sivigila**.

Se usa la **función instr** para buscar una subcadena dentro de una cadena.

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó a la primera. Gracias por el aporte.

Comment: @npovea, que bueno que te funciono!!!, podrías por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada, gracias